# Writing data from buffer to wave file on disk

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, audio-recording, wave

I'm writing a program which play wave file using waveOutOpen and PlaySound. Now I must write a function to record voice from microphone in Wave file on disk. I use writeInOpen and waveInAddBuffer to record sound in buffer but i can't find an easy class to manipulate on wave file and copy buffer content to file .wav. Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: What language are you using?..

Comment: The program must be wrote in MFC, so in C++, VS 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the file yourself.

You can use the [Multimedia File I/O API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743576.aspx), specifically at [`mmioOpen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757331.aspx), [`mmioCreateChunk()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757317.aspx), [`mmioAscend()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757315.aspx), and [`mmioWrite()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757341.aspx) functions.  You need a good understanding of how the WAVE file format works, how the `WAVEFORMAT/EX` structures work, etc so you know which pieces to write and how to write them correctly.

Or use DirectX's [DirectSound API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416960.aspx), specifically the [`IDirectSoundCaptureBuffer8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee418162.aspx) interface and the `CWaveFile` helper class:

[Writing to a WAV file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee419050.aspx)

Until you have an understanding of either approach, you should consider using an existing library to do the hard work for you, for example:

[Wave Class for Playing and Recording Wave Files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1325/Wave-Class-for-Playing-and-Recording-Wave-Files)